# Which download manager can tell the download queue size

Tags: windows, download-manager

I have [Internet Download Manager](http://internetdownloadmanager.com) installed but the problem is thus:

I have 200 links in the queue. I want to find that how much in total GB I have in the queue to download. Is there any download manager which can tell the size of all links which are in the queue?

Comment: Which operating system do you need this software for?

Comment: I thought I was the only one with that many downloads in my wish list.

Comment: os WINDOWS 7 OR VISTA